# how to get specific text after a div with xpath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

I get trouble to get specific texts which are located between two tags.
I mean, want to get `Text after em tag. I want to get this.` and also `text after this p tag. I also want to get this.`.
 is there any way of doing that?
thanks in advance.

```
<article>
    <h1 id='h1'>Heading 1</h1>
    <img src='mypath/pictures/pic.jpg'></img>
    <p></p>
    <div id='div1'>
        <time datetime='2016'>2016</time>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <em>my location, TN, United States</em>
     Text after em tag. I want to get this.
    <p></p>
    text after this p tag. I also want to get this.
    <div id='div2'>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Do you want together both text or separate??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur. both to gether

Answer (score 0):

you can get the following sibling texts by using

```
following-sibling::text()
```

so to get all the **em** after text

```
//em/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

the same will be for **p** tag, and then join them

```
string-join(em/following-sibling::text()[1] | p/following-sibling::text()[1] , ',')
```

I hope this could help!